# find filename without directory and extension from inside of a bash scriptfile

Tags: linux, bash, awk

As mentioned above,I have been trying to get the filename without its directory and extension from inside a bash script file.I want the output to be displayed as ->  filename : value of sum/count .I have tried using basename but it doesnt work.

```
FILE=$(find "$@" -type f -name "*.dat")
for contents in $FILE; do 
    awk -F "<Overall>" 'NF>=2 {count=count+1;sum=sum+$2; }
                        END {printf("%s:%4.1f\n",gensub(".dat","","g",FILENAME),sum/count);}' $contents
done| sort -k2rn
```

The output when the code is run,given a directory containing all the files  I need to check , as an argument are :

[image: this is the output]

I changed gensub part to basename $contents but it still doesnt work.Hope someone can help.Thank you very much!!

Comment: Where does "<Overall>" come from?

Comment: @karakfa it is a pattern i want to find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're removing the extension, but you're not removing the directory prefix. Try:

```
END {printf("%s:%4.1f\n", gensub(/.*\/(.*)\.dat$/, "\1", "g"), FILENAME), sum/count);}
```

`\1` gets the part of the regexp matched by `(.*)`, which is everything between the last `/` and `.dat`.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH...I have to put double backslash  before 1 and it works..thanks again!